# What language is being used in apt-get config files?

Tags: apt

For example, in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` we have something like this:

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};

// List of packages to not update (regexp are supported)
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
//  "vim";
//  "libc6";
//  "libc6-dev";
//  "libc6-i686";
};
```

What language is being used here?

Comment: Looks like a combination of list items and Perl, but I'm not sure that matches the "language".  What this reads like to me is `Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins` is Perl-ish, while `{ ... }` is just a semicolon delimited list of what's allowed as an origin point for unattended updates to handle.  Not 100% sure though, hence why I didn't write this as an answer.

Comment: I'm curious if this is completely made up, or is an actual standard.

Comment: Couldn't say, hence why comment and not answer.  Also entirely possible that while Perl-ish, it's really [its own configuration format/language](https://linux.die.net/man/5/apt.conf) that isn't truly any one language and is specific to that application.

Comment: Yep. That's my guess, but wanted to make sure :)